# What are the Latin lyrics to Ringo Starr's "Pax Um Biscum (Peace Be With You)"

Tags: song-lyrics, transcription

Happy Christmastime everyone!  Being this time of year I pulled out one of my favorite Christmas records, which is Ringo Starr's *I Wanna Be Santa Claus*.  The last track of the album is called "Pax Um Biscum (Peace Be With You)."  I was curious about what the lyrics to the song were, however when I tried to look them up only a few lines of the song have been transcribed.  After some research, I think the language in the song could possibly be Latin.  I was wondering if that was correct, and if so, what are the lyrics?  I don't need a translation, just a transcription of the song's lyrics.

Here's the link to the song for reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDdgg5OKQzc&ab_channel=RingoStarr-Topic

Answer (score 4):

The lyrics seem to be a corruption of:

> Pax Vobiscum

This means, "Peace be with you." The subsequent lyrics of the song confirm this.

Though this particular phrase doesn't occur in the Gospel narrative, the angel choir's song in Luke 2:14 is quite similar:

> Gloria in altissimis Deo, Et in terra **pax hominibus** bonae voluntatis.

Concerning the reason for the strange corruption, my guess (given the stereotypically "Eastern" sounds of the song) is that it's some kind of reference to the [Om mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om).